# xrandr doesn't see HDMI

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, xrandr

Ubuntu 15.10

Linux ag 4.2.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 8 15:35:06 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
$ xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768      60.00*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Before reboot the HDMI display was there, now it is not. Any clues on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

I am using a laptop with NVIDIA Optimus with HDMI output apparently wired to the NVIDIA card, but not to the Intel card.

My system had drivers both for Intel and NVIDIA cards.

After I uninstalled with purge Intel drivers (along with bumblebee stuff), I was able to `prime-switch` to the NVIDIA card. After two reboots HDMI output reappeared.